# Is it possible to quantize a tensorflow \ keras model without converting it to tflite?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to quantize a keras model to optimize runtime based on [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/post_training_quantization)
The process fails because of missing support for some opcodes in tflite ([a known issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/21526))
I want to know if it's possible to quantize the model without also converting it to tflite, so the missing opcodes support wouldn't be a problem